# How to get the push id of a specific value in android using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I get the push id of the value where child("topic_name").getValue() = "algebre" ?
FirebaseDatabase Structure:

[image]

I have already tried push().getKey(); but it returns another key to me.

Comment: you want to get root node id or child nood inside id.

Comment: any luck on solving this @GradiMut?

Comment: Yes it's now working perfectly... thank you @LeviAlbuquerque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = reference.child(TOP_NODE_NAME).orderByChild("topic_name").equalTo("algebre");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String key = child.getKey();
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Now `key` has the Key of the node where `topic_name=algebra`